# Vue.js proper vue-router styling

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js

I'm new to vue/webpack and I can't find a proper way to use scss files in a project that use vue-routing.

here is the project structure:

```
/src
  /routes
    route1.vue
    route1.js
    route2.vue
    route2.js
    ...
  /scss
    main.scss
    mixins.scss
    route1.scss
    route2.scss
    ...
  main.js
index.html
```

the code of route1.vue (and route2, except from the script src) is:

```
<template>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="./route1.js"></script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "../scss/main";
</style>
```

the main.js manages the routing (as found on the tutorial)

When I run the project in dev mode by webpack, I've found that everytime I load a routing component, on the index page the tag style with all the contents of the main.scss is duplicated for each routing.

How can I avoid it?

Where should I put the scss import to include it on time only? 
Should I wrap the routing inside a top level component?
(that seems quite complicated...)

Should I use a different approach?
(I've used for a long time grunt/angular and maybe I'm trying to port a pattern that doesn't fit this tool...)

Comment: First of all make sure that you have proper Webpack loaders installed. Read [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html) guide. Then use `@import` in one of `.js` files like `main.js`. Lastly add a link in your `index.html` to created style file.

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually I've asked this question after reading that guide, mostly because I didn't understand it and it doesn't give a full coverage of a pipeline working with a css preprocessor. About the second part of your message, with @import do you mean importing the scss resource in javascript? and about the index.html, where should the link point to?

Comment: OK, I'll try to clarify that by posting a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to install these modules/loaders:

   - css-loader
   - sass-loader
   - node-sass
   - extract-text-webpack-plugin
2. In `webpack.config.js` add these:

`var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');` before `module.exports = {...}`

then in `rules[]` define these two rules:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
  }
```

then, after the end of `module: {...}` add this:

```
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
],
```

that's it for webpack configurations.

3. Now you have to write your scss rules in a file, let's say `app.scss` for example.

import that file by putting the import statement in one of your `.js` file, like `main.js`:

`import 'path/to/app.scss'`

4. Finally, you need to reference the stylesheet file in your `index.html`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/style.css">`

By now, When you build the project with webpack, it will translate your scss rules to css and put the stylesheet in `dist/style.css`

Hope you will find it informative. :)